# How to upload a file/image to Azure Blob using React Native (Expo)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, azure-storage, expo

I am trying to figure out how to upload an image to Azure Blob in React Native (Expo) without ejecting it from the Expo. So `rn-fetch-blob` and `react-native-azure-blob-storage` do not work in my case as they require ejecting from the Expo.

I was thinking of using a solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58687519/how-to-upload-a-csv-file-to-blob-storage-using-axios-fetch-nodejs), but I wonder if there is a better solution out there. Do you know any? Please let me/us know.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use SDK to upload a file, then you can upload a file via REST API. The solution you found is correct, it uses the storage account key to compute a signature to make your request authorized. It is a bit complex.

There is also an easier way. You can [authorize with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory). In this way, you can easily get an access token for accessing your storage account.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It is not that I do not want to use SDK. It is that it does not work with React Native. It seems that relies heavily on browser/node API's.

Comment: do you know how can I compute a signature in React Native context?

Comment: You can find the it in the solution you have found: `var signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from(storageKey, 'base64')).update(stringToSign, 'utf-8').digest('base64');`.

Comment: I suggest you use AAD authentication. You just need to send a POST request, then you will get an access token.

Comment: Hmm... Does crypto package compatible with React Native Expo?